# arduino and raspberry pi serial port slow

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi2, pyserial

I have application uses serial port to send data from odroid xu4 to Arduino pro mini, the data is packages of 10 bytes i use "`Serial_Port.write(struct.pack('cBBBBBBBBB', "R", cmd[0], cmd[1], cmd[2], cmd[3], cmd[4], cmd[5], cmd[6], cmd[7], cmd[8]))`" and the odroid send two packages every 20 millisecond (50Hz), on the arduino this is the code:

ARDUINO CODE:

```
#include <Wire.h>

char CMD[] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
char hand;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
  Serial.println("Arduinno serial to I2C converter 115200");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() == 10) {
    Serial.readBytes(CMD, 10);
    Serial.println(CMD);
  }
}
```

i use two XBee PRO S2C to transmit the data from XU4 to the Arduino, i connect the XBee with XU4 using Tx Rx pins, port: '/dev/ttySAC0'.

when i run the programs the Arduino receives only the first two or three frames of data then it stops working until i press the reset button.
can any one help me with this problem, it take me a lot of time searching for solution but no good results.
also i tried to replace the Arduino with raspberry Pi B+ but same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an arduino spcialist, but I would suggest changing

```
if (Serial.available() == 10) {
```

to

```
if (Serial.available() >= 10) {
```

The current code relies on there being *exactly* one message available. If the Python code manages to send two messages in the time between subsequent reads, the current code will fail.